# How do I test image recognition algorithms?

Tags: testing, language-agnostic, computer-vision, image-recognition

Suppose I have a function of the type

```
[(ObjectType, (x, y))] <= identify (Image img)
```

where `identify` is a function that takes an `Image` and returns a list of `Object` - coordinate pairings, where each coordinate represents the location of the object in the image (in pixels).

1. Assuming I have some sample images, how should I go about testing my
   `identify` function?
2. Do I have to manually segment the test images or is there an easier
   way?
3. Are there any techniques when working with video instead of images?

Comment: Have a look at the computer vision datasets - usually all manual work have been done already. http://www.cvpapers.com/datasets.html

Comment: @old-ufo Unfortunately I'm working in a bit of a niche so I'm not sure how helpful general datasets will be. I will go through them and see if anything is similar, though, thanks!

Comment: If you have to make your own data, try LabelMe - http://labelme.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/ - good tool for different labeling.

Comment: I'll try to answer, tell me if that helps:
1. Compute ROC curves. 
2. It will be far more realistic and challenging to feed your algorithm with real work, un-cropped images. But for the ground truth, you would have to know the location of the images in the image.
3. you can use "labelMe video" for labeling and separate the video into images to feed them to the algorithm. 

Hope that help, please comment if you have other questions.

Comment: @old-ufo Thank you, I will make use of it.

Comment: @GilLevi Thanks, that's helpful. If you pose it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer:

1. Compute ROC curves.
2. It will be far more realistic and challenging to feed your algorithm with real work, un-cropped images. But for the ground truth, you would have to know the location of the images in the image.
3. you can use "labelMe video" for labeling and separate the video into images to feed them to the algorithm.

Hope that help, comment if you have any further questions.